# SQL Server - Update a column if row is the first record in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update

How do i identify the first row that has value for each Brand and Category, then update Column "FirstValue" as 1, else 0?
e.g of expected table

```
Date   |  Brands  |  Category |  Value  | FirstValue 
Jan 08 |   A      |  1        | 0       |0
Jan 08 |   A      |  2        | 0       |0
Jan 08 |   A      |  3        | 0       |0
Jan 08 |   B      |  1        | 12      |1
Jan 08 |   B      |  2        | 0       |0
Jan 08 |   B      |  3        | 0       |0
Feb 08 |   A      |  1        | 5       |1
Feb 08 |   A      |  2        | 0       |0
Feb 08 |   A      |  3        | 67      |1
Feb 08 |   B      |  1        | 0       |0
Feb 08 |   B      |  2        | 0       |0
Feb 08 |   B      |  3        | 6       |1
```

Comment: Is the earliest date indicative of first?

Comment: Also what is the primary key for this table please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) are actually updatable, and combining CTEs with ranking functions [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) gives a perfect solution:

```
with cte as (
 select row_number() over (partition by Brand, Category order by Date) as rn
, FirstValue
from Table)
update cte
set FirstValue = case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end;
```

Comment: i encounter an error : Incorrect Syntax near the keyword "Group"

Comment: we can use group by in the parameter?

Comment: it works now. :)
not sure if it's because i changed group to partition.

Thankyou!