# Mysql Update Query for sample table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 1 table called sample and it has 3 columns.

```
id   customer   default_address

1     1         0   
2     1                 0

3     1         0   
4     1         0   
5     2         0   
6     2         0   
7     3         0   
8     3         0   
9     2         0

10    2         0
```

Here I want to group by customer and update first default address should be 1 and rest all for 0 for every customer. How to do it mysql query?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154911/sql-server-update-a-column-if-row-is-the-first-record-in-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  tb a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer, MIN(id) id
            FROM    tb
            GROUP   BY customer
        ) b ON a.customer = b.customer AND
                a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.default_address = b.ID IS NOT NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf32a0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE sample 
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT MIN(id) id,customer 
   FROM sample 
   GROUP BY customer) t ON sample.customer=t.customer 
SET default_address="1" 
WHERE sample.id=t.id;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table1 
INNER JOIN (Select Min(`id`) as MinID,`customer`
From Table1 Group by `customer`) t2
SET Table1.`default_address` = 1
WHERE Table1.`id` = t2.MinID;
```

**[*SAMPLE FIDDLE*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/623e7/1)**